# final output was not reflecting in csv, Need to fix output in data frame

Tags: python, json, pandas, list, dataframe

Question - I need to get data from this given link and save as a csv format. Required data's are price, previous close, symbol.

I am a beginner, I don't know how to frame data, could pls help me with a reference code.

Any other alternative methods also fine.

```
#input data was given below
tikcer  = ['msft','amd','aapl']
```

Expecting output format-

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 261.5 | 266.82 | MSFT |
| 1 | 94.24 | 102.47 | AMD |
| 2 | 145.54 | 149.24 | AAPL |

I am getting this output -

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 145.54 | 149.24 | AAPL |

My testing code

```
import json
import requests
#import pyuser_agent
import pandas as pd
#ua = pyuser_agent.UA()
#headers = {'User-Agent': ua.random }
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)' }
tikcer  = ['msft','amd','aapl']
for i in tikcer:
  print(i)
  url = f"https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/{i}"
  response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
  print("API is working. status code :" + str(response.status_code))
  datas = json.loads(response.text)
  for value in datas['chart']['result']:
    print(value)
    a = value['meta']['previousClose']
    b = value['meta']['regularMarketPrice']
    c = value['meta']['symbol']
    print(a,b,c)
    data = {'A': a, 'B': b, 'C': c}
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([data])
    df.to_csv('data3.csv')
    #df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'A': [a], 'B': [b], 'C': [c]})
    #df.to_csv('data1.csv')
```

Comment: Warm welcome to SO. Please help us to help you and improve your example code. Please remove the `pyuser_agent` and `request` part from your code. Give us a hard coded example of the input data. Also remove the useless `#` lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the beginning, a dataframe is created with NaN values (empty).
And in the loop, each cell is filled, where df.loc[i, 'A'], i is the index of the row (on the left) and 'A' is the column name.
Also, the loop is changed using range to access the indexes via i.

```
import json
import requests
#import pyuser_agent
import pandas as pd
#ua = pyuser_agent.UA()
#headers = {'User-Agent': ua.random }
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)' }
tikcer  = ['msft','amd','aapl']
df = pd.DataFrame(index=[0, 1, 2], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

for i in range(0,len(tikcer)):
  print(tikcer[i])
  url = f"https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/{tikcer[i]}"
  response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
  print("API is working. status code :" + str(response.status_code))
  datas = json.loads(response.text)
  df.loc[i, 'A'] = datas['chart']['result'][0]['meta']['previousClose']
  df.loc[i, 'B'] = datas['chart']['result'][0]['meta']['regularMarketPrice']
  df.loc[i, 'C'] = datas['chart']['result'][0]['meta']['symbol']


print(df)
```

Output

```
        A        B     C
0   266.2   255.34  MSFT
1  102.47    96.89   AMD
2  149.24  141.809  AAPL
```